# Paypal Invoice API Internal Error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm writing trying to access the Invoice API with Perl (in Sandbox).

I've managed to create an invoice via the API, using CreateInvoice and can see the Invoice fine. So I think all the credentials/headers etc are fine.

I seem to be unable to SendInvoiceRequest or CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest though.

I note if I simply navigate in my browser to https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Invoice/CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest or
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Invoice/SendInvoiceRequest

It returns an 'internal server error', which is exactly the same as a receive from an API request.

Whereas if I navigate to 
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Invoice/CreateInvoice I get a response at least (credentials incorrect which I would expect).

Are the first examples 2 the correct endpoints, or is there some other issue with sending invoice requests ?

The content I'm sending is simply

```
invoice.merchantEmail=paypal-facilitator%40myemail.com&invoice.number=100001
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you are posting to the sandbox environment using the TLS connection and you should not use the SSL3 connection in the sandbox mode .

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming as I can create an invoice via the API all that is working fine. Its just whenever I try anything to send an invoice, and I note that even simple navigating to the url shows an internal error (whereas normally other Paypal API endpoints produce some response).

Comment: Did you get any correlation id in the response from the PayPal when you post it using the API call?If yes , you can paste here.

Comment: Doh, I'm an idiot, its CreateAndSendInvoice and not CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest! I know get a correlationid I can work with, thanks Eshan.

Comment: Glad to fixed it yourself !!!